# Webstorm IDE 2016.2.1 React JSX and ECMAScript 6

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, reactjs

I just got an update for WebStorm and I noticed they separated the support for React JSX (before it was JSX Harmony) but now it does not highlight keywords like yield and let, even though it recognizes them.

Does anyone know how to configure this?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22542 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22740 -- wait for 2016.2.2 as I understand.

Comment: D: too bad.. ok I'll wait I guess then post the answer with the update changelog

Comment: Well .. EAP build will be available before that (maybe next week .. or even this one) -- just keep an eye on https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ (RSS feed is available)

Comment: 2016.2.2 RC is here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP